# Using quotes inside a ngif expression in Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, angular-ng-if

I have been looking into this for a while and I cant find an answer that actually works. The problem is as follows, I am using an ngif expression like this:

```
<span *ngIf="client.status == '"XRG3306"'">
   <i class="fa fa-check" style="color: green"></i>
</span>
```

So the issue is the "XRG3306" value that is store in the client's db with the quotes, so how can I insert the quotes in the expression without breaking it. I already tried writing it like **'\"XRG3306\"'** and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ?

```
<span *ngIf="client.status === '&#34;XRG3306&#34;'">
```

this mean you have to transform your string with replace though...

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/V6z3zGR3t1eglBMD7xtB?p=preview)

Comment: will definitely keep this in mind, but I was going through a painful table migration program I created to remove those shitty " from all the records.

Comment: No, I wrote a small program inside the sql server to port the database to another temporal database to read data from, because my actual program doesnt modify data, it basically just reads it.